# Zomming in UIWebView

Tags: ios4

I am using standard UIWebView on iPhone to display some HTML page. But is there any way that I can DISABLE Zoom-Out (If the Zooming level is < 1) ?

The scenario is that now, user can use multitouch guesture to do zooming on my UIWebView. But it is UGLY to zoom out (while multi-touching). It shows the shadow and background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that there's no way to prevent zooming out.
You can, however, easily disable zooming at all by adding a meta-tag to your HTML's head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
```